# roundcube PHP Error message: Failed to load config from

Tags: roundcube

I have a problem to send a message with roundcube (Ubuntu 16.04) and I use Ispconfig.

[27-Apr-2017 15:18:50 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/jqueryui/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (POST /webmail/?_task=login?_task=login&_action=login)

[27-Apr-2017 15:18:51 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/zipdownload/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (GET /webmail/?_task=mail)

[27-Apr-2017 15:18:51 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/jqueryui/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (GET /webmail/?_task=mail)

[27-Apr-2017 15:18:51 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/zipdownload/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (GET /webmail/?_task=mail&_action=list&_refresh=1&_mbox=INBOX&_remote=1&*unlock=loading1493321550329&*=1493321550199)

[27-Apr-2017 15:18:51 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/zipdownload/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (GET /webmail/?_task=mail&_action=getunread&_page=1&_remote=1&*unlock=0&*=1493321550200)

[27-Apr-2017 15:18:59 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/zipdownload/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (GET /webmail/?_task=mail&_caps=pdf%3D0%2Cflash%3D1%2Ctif%3D0&_uid=4&_mbox=INBOX&_action=show)

[27-Apr-2017 15:18:59 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/jqueryui/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (GET /webmail/?_task=mail&_caps=pdf%3D0%2Cflash%3D1%2Ctif%3D0&_uid=4&_mbox=INBOX&_action=show)

[27-Apr-2017 15:18:59 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/zipdownload/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (GET /webmail/?_task=mail&_action=pagenav&_uid=4&_mbox=INBOX&_remote=1&*unlock=loading1493321558736&*=1493321558615)

[27-Apr-2017 15:18:59 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/zipdownload/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (GET /webmail/?_task=mail&_action=getunread&_remote=1&*unlock=0&*=1493321558616)

[27-Apr-2017 15:19:03 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/zipdownload/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (GET /webmail/?_task=mail&_reply_uid=4&_mbox=INBOX&_action=compose)

[27-Apr-2017 15:19:03 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/jqueryui/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (GET /webmail/?_task=mail&_reply_uid=4&_mbox=INBOX&_action=compose)

[27-Apr-2017 15:19:03 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/zipdownload/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (GET /webmail/?_task=mail&_action=compose&_id=65983082590244279663e)

[27-Apr-2017 15:19:03 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/jqueryui/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (GET /webmail/?_task=mail&_action=compose&_id=65983082590244279663e)

[27-Apr-2017 15:19:07 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/zipdownload/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (POST /webmail/?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1493321566133&_lang=en&_framed=1?_task=mail&_action=send)

[27-Apr-2017 15:19:07 -0400]:  PHP Error: Failed to load config from /var/lib/roundcube/plugins/jqueryui/config.inc.php in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_plugin.php on line 157 (POST /webmail/?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1493321566133&_lang=en&_framed=1?_task=mail&_action=send)

I don't know what I have to do ...

Thanks

Comment: I didn't find a solution; so I installed squiremail

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the latest version of ISPconfig (3.1.7), then do the following:

```
apt-get install php7.0-soap
```

Roundcube plugins works with **soap** and the ISPconfig does not install the library by default at the time of PHP installation.

Answer (score 0):

I silenced these error messages by adding the line:

> $config['fnord'] = 1;

to the `config.inc.php` file (e.g. `/usr/share/roundcube/plugins/jqueryui/config.inc.php`) inside the `<?php … ?>` block. This sets a dummy setting. It seems that Roundcube expects to find at least one setting in a config file.

I am not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem, but it works for me. :-)